# jQuery: add border on hovered element but NOT parents

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
var originalBorder = container.css("border");    
container.hover(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid "+options.color);
       },function(){
            $(this).css("border", originalBorder);
       });
```

Which I am using to add a border to the currently hovered element. However for example if a `span` is inside a `div` they are both getting borders. I only want to target the `span`. I thought that adding `event.stopPropagation()` would do the trick (*this is what I would do in Flex, which is what I am more used to*) but I guess this is a **live** event which I dont even understand what that means. So basically how can target the youngest element without triggering the parents?

Thanks!!

### update

Some more info. I am trying to add this effect to every element. so I am actually added the effect to the `div` and the `span` but I only want the `div` to be triggered when it is the youngest element that is hovered. And when a younger element is hovered like a `span` within a `div` then only the `span` is triggered. The code above is a plugin and I am calling it like this: `#("*").doBorders()`

Comment: This should work, where is `container` defined, and can you post some sample markup?

Comment: @Nick the first line inside my plugin is  var container = this;

Comment: I see what you mean (in your update), the reason they're both getting a border added isn't because the event is 'propagated' but because, technically, the mouse is hovered-over both elements, since the child is contained within the parent.

Comment: @Bobby, yes! Is there a work-around tho? Maybe a way to iterate over children and see if any are hovered or not? (which I know is probably not a very elegant solution)

Comment: hmm.. see update below, maybe you can solve it from the point of view that the on-hover function always clears all its parents' borders (or sets them to original), leaving only itself as having the new border (the innermost that is hovered-over)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's just a matter that your selector is selecting the container.

If you can, make sure the first selector is selecting the child--the child that you want to manipulate...

something like this:

```
    $(".childSpanClass").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid "+options.color);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css("border", originalBorder);
        }
    );
```

If you can't select the child there, then you could select the child inside the functions, like this:

```
    $(".container").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).children(".childClass").css("border", "1px solid "+options.color);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).children(".childClass").css("border", originalBorder);
        }
    );
```

**Update:**
Given your update, you might want to try going at it from the point of view of the child clearing the parents borders:

```
$(".container").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).parents().css("border", "");
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid blue");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css("border", "");
    }
);
```

Comment: My first selected is selecting like this: $("*").doBorders();

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second code snippet is what you want - I've done something very similar, the $(this) inside the function points to the each container select, and further select from its children the child you want to manipulate for the effect

Comment: Yes the 3rd one is the one I want. Clever solution! I wonder if there is a way to capture the parents previous border and restore it instead of clearing it (so I am not clearing one if one already existed) but any attempts will probably just give me the new border I am adding. But I guess that is a different issue.